# static in interfaces

Tags: c#, serialization, interface, model, ado

i want to write my own serialisation (xml and binary do not fit for me,
i want "a more ADO" way)

so i defined an interface:

```
interface ISerializeData
{
    DataTable GetDataSchema();
    DataTable SerializeData();
    object DeserializeData(DataTable data);
}
```

now i do not want to create an instance of an object to let
me get the schema for that object.

And: DeserializeData should return an instance, not use an instance.
Therefore i think it should be also static. (okay, it can initialize
an instancce from a datatable...)

Any ideas? How can i model that? static is not allowed in
interfaces and my classes already inherit from another abstract
base class.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: :) if this will be static why u need an interface? you can as well just create static class and implement your methods.

Comment: because i have more than one class that should have that semantics. static class is not an option, i want to serialize it and work with more than one instance of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that issue is why the other serializer utilize attributes as they allow you to provide metadata about how the class is to be stored with out forcing you to deal with the implementation of the class itself.

Comment: quite heavy for what i want to do. perhaps i write some helper classes.

Comment: accepted this as answer, because reflection and attributes are the only way to properly do what i want to do. just thought some guru would come up with a better idea than the "dirty" solution i have at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but this is really more a task for a utility class. Take `DeserializeData`, for instance. Somewhere in your code you decide which type you're going to construct. In your proposed code you would choose the type and call its static method. Now what? Would each type have its own code to do the serialization? You'd probably end up creating some class doing all the work, to stay DRY. So you might as well have one `DeserializeData` method in a utility class, like:

```
public static T DeserializeData(DataTable data)
    where T : new
{
    var T = new T();
    .... // Set properties
}
```

In this method you'd probably get the data schema.

Maybe `SerializeData()` could be an instance method, but that too would delegate its work to some utilty class.

Please let me know if I completely misunderstood your question.

Comment: But the schema is part of the model class, it is just an other represention than class. For now i wrote a bunch of utility class, perhaps i have the time to do this with attributes and reflection in future.